# How to find phase spectrum of an image in opencv python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find the phase spectrum of an image after applying DFT in python, here is the code i have used.
`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img=cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/IP assg2/im1.jpg')

img = cv2.cvtColor(sm1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
```

`

I am not sure how to move on from here, as all the tutorials i have come across are related to MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img=cv2.imread('input.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dft = np.fft.fft2(img)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
phase_spectrum = np.angle(dft_shift)

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.imshow(phase_spectrum, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```